# most common way to deal with endianness and files C++

Tags: c++, endianness

I started out just reading/writing 8-bit integers to files using chars. It was not very long before I realized that I needed to be able to work with more than just 256 possible values. I did some research on how to read/write 16-bit integers to files and became aware of the concept of big and little endian. I did even more research and found a few different ways to deal with endianness and I also learned some ways to write endianness-independent code. My overall conclusion was that I have to first check if the system I am using is using big or little endian, change the endianness depending on what type the system is using, and then work with the values.

The one thing I have not been able to find is the **best/most common** way to deal with endianness when reading/writing to files in C++ (no networking). So how should I go about doing this? To help clarify, I am asking for the best way to read/write 16/32-bit integers to files between big and little endian systems. Because I am concerned about the endianness between different systems, I would also like a cross-platform solution.

Comment: If you are using file on same system (no transfer of files involed between different system) than you do not need to worry about endianness, system will take care of that.

Comment: What kind of application? What kind of data? What volume (kilobytes or petabytes)? How is it accessed? What is the cost of the data? How future proof do you want it to be? Please **edit your question** to improve it and *motivate it*.

Comment: TL;DR. You can make your custom file format and decide an endianness to use on all files. I use boost.endian : you have a lot of functions like native_to_big, little_to_native etc. You also have custom integer types which have same endianness even in memory. Take a look: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/endian/doc/conversion.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most common way is simply to pass your in-memory values through htons() or htonl() before writing them to the file, and also pass the read data through ntohs() or ntohl() after reading it back from the file.    (htons()/ntohs() handle 16-bit values, htonl()/ntohl() handle 32-bit values)

When compiled for a big-endian CPU, these functions are no-ops (they just return the value you passed in to them verbatim), so the values will get written to the file in big-endian format.  When compiled for a little-endian CPU, these functions endian-swap the passed-in value and return the swapped version, so again the values will get written to the file in big-endian format.

That way the values in the file are always stored in big-endian format, and they always get converted to/from the appropriate (CPU-native) format when being transferred to/from memory.  This is the simplest way to do it (since you don't have to write or debug any conditional logic), and the most common (these functions are implemented and available on just about all platforms)

Comment: I agree with everyone that my question was too broad but this is the answer I was looking for. I wanted a simple and commonly-used solution, and this is much simpler than what I was going to do.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, a good habit is to avoid binary data (to exchange data between computers) and prefer [text files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file) and textual protocols to exchange data. You could use textual formats like [JSON](http://json.org/), YAML, XML, .... (or sometimes invent your own). There are many C++ libraries related to them, e.g. [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp).

Textual data is indeed more verbose (takes more disk space) and slightly slower to parse (but the disk I/O is often the bottleneck, not the CPU time "wasted" in parsing or encoding formats like JSON) but is much easier to work on.

Read also about [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). You'll find lots of libraries doing that (using some "common" well defined data format such as [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) or [ASN1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One)). Many file formats contain some header describing the concrete encoding. The [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) format is a good example of that.

Be aware that most of the time the data is more valuable (economically) than the software working on it. So it is very important to document very well how your data is organized in files.

Consider also using [databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database). Sometimes simply using [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) with tables containing JSON is very effective.

<sup>PS. Without an actual real world case, your question is too broad, and has no meaningful universal answer. There is no single best way!</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Basile, I agree that there is no universal answer.

In my world, embedded real time systems, using a text representation is blasphemy. Textual representations and JSON is at least 2 orders of magnitude slower than binary representations. It may be fine for the web. But that makes a difference when you have to process several kilo bytes of data per seconds (to handle voice for instance) across DSPs and GPPs.

For a more in depth discussion on this toppic, check out [chapter 7](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter7) of the ZeroMQ book.